# Force div's inserted into a container by JQuery to remain on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm aware many similar questions have been asked but none seem to really answer my question. Essentially I have a container div in which I am inserting (through JQuery) new div's via draggable/droppable as the new div's fill the container they begin to jump down to a new line. I need them to stay on the same line and cause the container to scroll horizontally.

Here's a part of my HTML

```
<label for="builder">Builder Area:</label>
<div id="builder">
    <div class="layer" data-layer='0'></div>
</div>
```

The "chunks" that are inserted into the layers:

```
<div class='chunk' id='"+chunk_id+"'>Chunk:"+chunk_id+"</div>"
```

code to insert the "chunks":

```
$(".layer").droppable({
    accept: "#chunk_drag",
    activeClass: "ui-active",
    hoverClass: "ui-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        // Create a new Chunk
        var chunk = "<div class='chunk' id='"+chunk_id+"'>Chunk:"+chunk_id+"</div>";
        chunk_id++;

        // Add the Chunk into the layer
        $(this).append(chunk);

        return true;
    },
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.layer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #222222;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.chunk {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #222222;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 5px;
    margin : 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about jQuery so much as CSS. Add a `white-space: nowrap;` attribute to your `.layer` rule so the browser knows to layout the inline contents of `.layer` on a single line, rather than the default behavior of wrapping. (**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/huhaqa)**)

```
.layer {
...
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This works although it causes the "chunks" to fail to wrap which is an undesirable behavior for my purpose, however simply adding 

    white-space: normal;

to the .chunk css fixes that so we're good here. Thank you Palpatim